# Formatting problem when using \figure and \subsection

Tags: floats, formatting

I am trying to write a research report. In it, I want to include figures inside a \subsection. However, whenever I put the figure inside the subsection, the figure is placed outside of the subsection. How can I keep the figure inside its subsection?

In the attached picture you can see the figures being placed above their subsection header. They should be underneath the subsection header.

Thanks!

[image: Figures outside of subsection]

Comment: You need `\usepackage{float}` and `\begin{figure}[H]`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. If you want to decide where a float is placed, you can indeed do what the comment above suggests. Or you could trust LaTeX in placing those figures for you to make the text better to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two primary suggestions:

- Most importantly, replace the first `\begin{figure}` directive after `\subsection` with `\begin{figure}[h!]`. The `h!` option means, "I want it here, really!". LaTeX will obey *unless* there simply isn't enough space left on the page to place the figure (including the caption); if that's the case, the figure will be placed at the top of the next page.
- Use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage` (3 instances). That way, any pending `figure` and `table` floats will get flushed from the stack.

Three further suggestions:

- Don't use the same `\label` argument more than once.
- Since you presumably want the two figures to be placed on one and the same page, use just one `figure` environment, not two separate ones.

  ```
  \begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering

  \includegraphics[...]{...}
  \caption{...}

  \bigskip

  \includegraphics[...]{...}
  \caption{...}

  \end{figure}
  ```
- Write either `8\textdegree\ Angle of Attack` or `8\textdegree{} Angle of Attack` as the argument of `\subsection`. That way, there will be a proper word space between `8\textdegree` and `Attack`.